# bag file request

Tags: rosbag, sensor-msgs, bagfiles, bagfile, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a project that requires collecting a large set of data; anything from a few hours to a week's worth of scan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan) and tf (tf/tfMessage) topics, preferably recorded from the same environment (one floor of a university building, office, lab, etc). It's fine if people are present in the observed environment.

Before setting out to record the bag file(s) for this task, I thought I'd ask to see if anyone had already collected data similar to what I've described and would be willing to share it.

General requirements:

- Bag file of recorded scan and tf topics.
- Recorded in the same environment.
- 5hours + (the more data the better!).
- People present in the environment is okay.

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58382/bag-file-request/) by [coli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4451/coli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like a bag-sharing website would be useful, doesn't it? A bit of a long shot, but you could try contacting  [Frank Schneider](http://forum.eurathlon2013.eu/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=54&sid=3da5ff9b72956db7742e92e18e382660), the organizer of Eurathlon, he has access to some nice datasets:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gA1_UblFgIE

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9AkicY6f_I

---

Originally posted by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) with karma: 435 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0